# Can a landlord ask you for income verification in middle of lease term?

Tags: real-estate

I have lived here for 8 months. I filled out the application on line and gave them the income verification and the money to move in.you can't get approved or accepted into apartments if you don't give them your income verification.After being here 8 months they somehow don't have e it a d need it for recent? Are they allowed to do this? They also changed my lease around and added new rules and put it in my original lease like it was there when I moved in. Those were not on the lease when I signed. And they are threatening me to sign or get out now and give them income verification now or leave. I been here 8 Months.  I pay on time. I never bother anyone.

Comment: Where in the world does this relate to?

Comment: How long was the lease period, and the period of notice? In some jurisdictions (for example UK) they need to give you notice even though the lease has a fixed term. Therefore the lease needs to be renewed before that period of notice required from them. They can't tell you to "get out now".

Comment: My lease is 13months. I ha e only been here 8months. I have 60 days to tell them if I'm renewing my lease or not. This has nothing to do w lease renewals. It's just there way of violating my rights. Out of the hundreds of people who live here I'm the only one they want income verification from in the middle of my lease term

Comment: Does your lease say anything about income verification?  If so then the income verification isn't necessarily simply a prerequisite for signing the lease.  If the lease doesn't say anything about income verification then they can't evict you for failing to provide it.  (It's also possible that they could be prohibited from evicting you even if the lease does say something about it, because the law governing residential leases where you live might forbid such terms in the lease.)

Comment: I think the OP can be improved any landlord can ask any tenant to sign anything. I think a charitable reading of this post may conclude that the auctual question wanting to be answered is can a landlord FORCE you to sign this.

Answer (score 1):

One party cannot unilaterally change a contract (obviously some edge-case exceptions apply, but we're talking the general case here).

You signed a lease.  That is the lease in effect.  I assume you kept a copy.  A sketchy landlord can try a hundred different things to try to convince you that other terms apply, **but they do not**.

All the landlord can do is not renew your lease at the end of its term.  If this isn't a concern for you, and you don't mind confrontation, tell them to get lost.

I will add that asking you for income verification or changing lease terms on their end isn't depriving you of any rights.  They haven't actually done anything to you yet.